# MySQL Using Connector/Python

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to connect to a database on a remote server in python, and I am using the following [guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-connecting.html)

There are two ways that are proposed

```
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='scott', password='password',
                              host='127.0.0.1',
                              database='employees')
print(cnx) # <mysql.connector.connection_cext.CMySQLConnection object at 0x0000023EDDCD9FA0>
print(cnx.is_connected()) # Gives FALSE
cursor = cnx.cursor() # Gives mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: MySQL Connection not available.
```

```
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.MySQLConnection(user='scott', password='password',
                                 host='127.0.0.1',
                                 database='employees')
print(cnx) # Gives <mysql.connector.connection.MySQLConnection object at 0x00000158D5C99FD0>
print(cnx.is_connected) # Gives TRUE
cursor = cnx .cursor() # No ERROR
```

I am getting error when using first method.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by using: `use_pure = True`
If you see the implementation of `connect()`

```
 if HAVE_CEXT and not use_pure:
        return CMySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
```